# Compare Two Arrays using Grep in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have two array of hashes.They are as below

```
my $arr1 =[{'mid_id' => '1'},{'mid_id' => '2'},{'mid_id' => '5'} ]; 
my $arr2 = [{'name' => 'Name1','id' => '1'},{'name' => 'Name2','id' => '2'},{'name' => 'Name6','id' => '6'}];
```

Now i want to get the name from the second array whose id matches two the first array.
I have tried by this way but i want to make this code more better is there any way to do this

```
foreach my $a1(@$arr1){

foreach (@$arr2){
        if($_->{id} eq $a1->{mid_id}){
                print "$_->{id} mapped to  $_->{name} \n";
        } else{
                print "no match $_->{id} \n";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `grep` like the following.  The only trick is that you need to test if you actually found a match:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (
    { 'mid_id' => '1' },
    { 'mid_id' => '2' },
    { 'mid_id' => '5' },
};

my @recs = (
    { 'name' => 'Name2', 'id' => '1' },
    { 'name' => 'Name',  'id' => '2' },
    { 'name' => 'VP',    'id' => '3' },
);

for my $hash (@array){
    my ($rec) = grep {$hash->{mid_id} eq $_->{id}} @recs;
    print "$hash->{mid_id} mapped to " . ($rec ? $rec->{name} : "<No Match>") . "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 mapped to Name2
2 mapped to Name
5 mapped to <No Match>
```